# in order to confess

Tags: clauses, active-vs-passive

a. He was tortured to confess to crimes he hadn't committed.

b. He was tortured to make him confess to crimes he hadn't committed.

c. He was tortured in order to confess to crimes he hadn't committed.

d. He was tortured in order to make him confess to crimes he hadn't committed.

Which of the above sentences are grammatically correct and meaningful?

Comment: You are asking for editing or polishing and we don't really do that here. Also, there is no input from you at all....

Comment: Thank you, Lambie. With all due respect, if I was writing something I would just avoid the problem by writing 'They tortured him to make him confess to crimes he hadn't committed." It'd be simpler and more direct and wouldn't need editing. This is a genuine grammatical issue. What is the implied subject of the infinitive 'to confess' in (a)? I think it cannot be 'he', but it is supposed to be. That's why I think the sentence is defective.

Comment: @azz Please say everything you're thinking and have thought of in the question. Don't make us do work you've already done. I could turn this question into a 1-hour lesson. Tx :)

Answer (score 1):

For a, the words *forced* or *made* or *induced* can be used that way:
*He was forced to confess.*
But *tortured* can't.

b works.

c and d are both wrong, because *in order to X* imputes purpose to an agent, who is unnamed in your sentences.
That phrase could work two different ways.
(with active verb)
They tortured him *in order to* make him confess.

(with passive verb)
He was tortured by the agent in order to make him confess.